# Using tikzplotlib for plotting a function in latex

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, latex, tikz

I have a question in python/latex. I want to use python to plot a function and to export it in latex code on such a way that the fontsize is the same in my latex document and the plot.
Now is my problem that the png output is not the same as the output of the tex document.

This is the png ouput:

[image]

And this is the output in my tex file:

[image]

Now is my question how can i make the latex output equal to the png output. And my other question is how can i adjust the size of the latex output. At the moment I am using pycharm.
The code of my python code is :

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tikzplotlib
i = True
if i == True:
    matplotlib.use("pgf")
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({
         "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
         'font.family': 'serif',
         'font.size': 12,
         'text.usetex': True,
         'pgf.rcfonts': False,
    })


def thermal_light_prob(n, mean_n):
    return mean_n**n/(mean_n+1)**(n+1)
fig = plt.figure()
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6, 4)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, hspace=0)
axs = gs.subplots(sharex=True, sharey = True)
x = np.linspace(0,15,16,endpoint=True)
#plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (6, 4)
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,sharex=True)

axs[0].bar(x,thermal_light_prob(x,1), label = r'$\left\langle{n}\right\rangle$ = 1')
axs[1].bar(x,thermal_light_prob(x,5), alpha = 0.75, label = r'$\left\langle{n}\right\rangle$ = 5')
axs[2].bar(x,thermal_light_prob(x,10), alpha = 0.50, label = r'$\left\langle{n}\right\rangle$ = 10')
axs[0].legend(loc = 'best')
axs[1].legend(loc = 'best')
axs[2].legend(loc = 'best')
fig.text(0.5, 0.02, 'photon number $n$', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, r'probability $P(n,\left\langle{n}\right\rangle)$ ', va='center', rotation='vertical')
#plt.ylim(0,2)
#plt.xlabel(r'delay time $\frac{\tau}{\tau_c}$')
if i == True:
    tikzplotlib.save(r'D:\Masterarbeit\Latexdokument\maske_fuer_stud_dip\maske_fuer_stud_dip\Grafiken\thermal_light_prob.tex')
else:
    plt.show()
```

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question in the direct way you are asking, but you could use matplotlib to export a `svg` instead of a `png` then use that in latex (still good solution because svg files are much better for plots than png).

Take a look at the matplotlib `savefig` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html). Simply specify the filetype as `svg` in the name and optionally the `format='svg'` parameter.

Note that you may need to use a different matplotlib [backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html).